Why does an exclamation point in Python give me "The system cannot find the file specified" error?
I was trying to do a negation of a boolean statement in Python, and I forgot that it's done with the 'not' keyword instead of the exclamation point as in != or Java. I did the following:
!(pd.Timestamp('2000-01-31') <= pd.NaT)

and got an The system cannot find the file specified. error. What is causing this output instead of some other error like a syntax error?

How did you run this? An IDE may interpret the ! As the start of its own command.

Exactly. It's not syntax for Python itself, but it is syntax for IPython, or IPython Notebook, or Jupyter Notebook, or similar tools.

Ah, this was in Debugger console of Pycharm.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

There was no traceback, just the output I said in the question.
